# Como passar números entre "{ }" na url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Estou com uma dúvida besta em uns exercícios usando Spring Boot.

O exercício exige que eu receba a lista de números da seguinte forma:

```
http://localhost:8080/listaDecrescente?lista={12,55,70,22}
```

E retorne a resposta:

```
HTTP 200 OK {70,55,22,12}
```

Ok, a lógica é simples. Minha dúvida é: como passo os parâmetros entre as chaves, igual o exemplo acima?

Como estou fazendo:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/listaDecrescente"})
    public int[] listaDecrescente(@RequestParam int[] lista){
        //lógica aqui...
        return lista;
}
```

A única forma que a minha URL aceita receber os dados:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/listaDecrescente?lista=12,55,70,22
```

Comment: Olá, eu sou novo no spring... mas tenta `List<Integer>`. Seu @RequestMapping esta estranho, pra que aquelas {} do lado de fora? deveria ser "/{lista}". Em último caso terás que ler como String e fazer o parse na mão mesmo... Mas deve ter forma melhor. Ainda, dou uma estrelinha pra quem me linkar onde na documentação do spring ele lista quais são os mapeamentos entre tipos do java e "parsers" de controller do spring. Porque, por exemplo, se você passe um DTO em um body ele faz o parse e validação automaticamente com as anotações de validation, onde está documentado isso?

Answer (score 1):

Não achei nada na documentação do Spring que suporte este formato usando chaves (ou colchetes):

```
lista={12,55,70,22}
```

**Porém**, o Spring aceita:

```
lista=12,55,70,22
```

Ou:

```
lista=12&lista=55&lista=70&lista=22
```

Usando, **respectivamente**:

```
public String metodo(@RequestParam String[] lista){

}
```

E:

```
public String metodo(@RequestParam List<String> lista){

}
```

No seu caso, então, acredito que a opção é receber a informação como uma `String` mesmo e fazer a leitura da informação para transformar ela em um *array*. Algo do tipo:

```
public String metodo(@RequestParam String lista){
    List<String> ids = lista
        .replace("{","") // remover o {
        .replace("}","") // remover o }
        .split(",");
}
```

Não vai ficar elegante, mas não vejo outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se você precisa que realmente o método seja GET, então a forma de envio seria essa que você falou:

```
listaDecrescente?lista=12,55,70,22
```

e se tivessem outros parametros você separaria por &...

```
listaDecrescente?lista=12,55,70,22&nome=nome passado&idade=20
```

Porém eu acredito que seria melhor você alterar o método de envio para POST, assim ficaria mais tranquilo para você passar a lista e outros parametros que existissem.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/detalha", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

ou

```
@PostMapping(value = "/listaDecrescente")
```

Espero ter ajudado!